# Substitutions not working in send grid via firebase functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, sendgrid

I am having troubles adding `substitutions` data to emails sent from Sendgrid via Firebase Cloud Functions.

Here is my `function`

```
exports.firestoreEmail = functions.firestore
.document('users/{id}')
  .onCreate(snap => {
    const user = snap.data();
    const msg = {
      to: user.email,
      from: 'example@example.com',
      subject: `${user.firstName}, please Verify Your Email Address`,
      templateId: 'templateID',
      substitutionWrappers: ['{{', '}}'],
      substitutions: {
        firstName: user.firstName,
        email: user.email,
        id: user.id
      }
    };
    return sgMail
      .send(msg)
      .then(() => console.log('email sent!'))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  });
```

and the **transactional** template for the `templateId` is

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>{{firstName}} - {{email}} - {{id}}</body>
</html>
```

This returns an email to the `user.email` as intended but with blanks where the `substitutions` data should be.

Following the documents and use cases [here](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/packages/mail/USE_CASES.md#transactional_templates) I have also tried adding

```
sgMail.setSubstitutionWrappers('{{', '}}');
```

to globally `setSubstitutionWrappers`. Still doesn't work.

I have also `console.log(user)` which returns the data to be passed to the `substitutions` in the console.

What am I missing? The data is available, the email is correctly formatted and the function follows exact to the SendGrid Cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to figure this out after many hours, realising that `substitutions` and `substitutionWrappers` are intended for **[Legacy Transactional Templates](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/packages/mail/USE_CASES.md#legacy-transactional-templates)**.

Instead for the `v3` **[API](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/packages/mail/USE_CASES.md#transactional-templates)** you should use `dynamic_template_data` instead of `substitutions` and the `substitutionWrappers` appear to be set as handlebars `{{ }}`.

```
  dynamic_template_data: {
    firstName: user.firstName,
    email: user.email,
    id: user.id
  }
```

Next time, I'll be sure to read and not skim the documentation... most likely not.

Comment: Great response, i was also lost there, this info is not easily available anywhere

Comment: Thank you alot, was watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JVy0JpCOuNI) but got stuck when params were not passed.